# Doctrine collection

Tags: sql, postgresql, doctrine

I have a project which contains a collection of article (articles) and I would like to have all project who have the article number 3 per example.

```
$qb = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->addSelect('a')
        ->leftJoin('p.articles', 'a')
        ->andWhere('a.id = :article')
        ->setParameter(':article', 3);
```

It takes all my project which contains the article 3 but if my project has the articles 1, 2, 3, then my request will take the project with only the article 3, I don't have the other. How can I have everything ?

I wanted to do something like :article IN p.articles but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution using MEMBER OF

```
$qb = $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->addSelect('a')
    ->leftJoin('p.articles', 'a')
    ->andWhere(':article MEMBER OF p.articles')
    ->setParameter(':article', 3);
```